# cannot add or remove an event handler "method group" but the designer can

Tags: c#, event-handling

When I try to add or remove an event handler the error is "cannot assign … to a "method group". Yet the exact line of code in the designer compiles fine.

I am filling in list boxes so the user can select the items.  There are several SelectedIndexChange fire backs that I do not want to fire until I have everything in place.  I no no trouble coded a numeric up-down to prevent it firing but I cant get the listbox coded and am forced to use semaphores to prevent unwanted things from happening. I looked at the VS2017 build "xxx.Designer.cs" and copied and pasted the exact line of code into the "xx.cs" but that  error shows up.

```
        {
            cb_AppNames_SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cb_AppNames_SelectedIndexChanged);
            FillAppBox();
            cb_AppNames_SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cb_AppNames_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

here is the code from the Designer.cs

````
            // cb_SelProj
            // 
            this.cb_SelProj.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.cb_SelProj.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 25);
            this.cb_SelProj.Name = "cb_SelProj";
            this.cb_SelProj.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(279, 21);
            this.cb_SelProj.TabIndex = 0;
            this.cb_SelProj.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cb_SelProj_SelectedIndexChanged);```

fixme1.png shows error messaged and fixme2 shows code that has no err
![1](http://stateson.net/images/fixme1.png)
![2](http://stateson.net/images/fixme1.png)
````

Comment: Those two statements are not equivalent. Why would you think that they were?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically correct but the actual problem was (1) about 3 in morning looking at this, (2) was unable to get .png file to show up at this forum - still do not know what I did wrong, and (3) due to not being able to see the .png in the "big screen" so I did not notice I was using "_" instead of "." when I tried to code the following up

```
this.cb_AppNames.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cb_AppNames_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

I was using small font in VS2017 for code and did not see the problem though it is plain here:

```
this.cb_AppNames.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cb_AppNames_SelectedIndexChanged);
this.cb_AppNames_SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cb_AppNames_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

An event (like `SelectedIndexChanged`) is like a list of callbacks, which are called when the event occours. If you don't want/need this event before you filled your listbox, then do not add the callback by designer, but in your code after filling the data.

In your example you don't use the same code as in designer. The desigener adds the **method** `b_SelProj_SelectedIndexChanged`. In your code you try to remove and add the **event** `cb_AppNames_SelectedIndexChanged` itself. This will not work. You can only add and remove a method to or from an event.